# JavaScript: Add key to array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I assign a key to array elements using the `map` function?

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

// what i want.
arr = [{t: 1}, {t: 2}, {t: 3}, {t: 4}, {t: 5}, {t: 6}, {t: 7}, ]
```

Comment: Tag the language, and please explain what `t` is meant to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```js
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let list = arr.map(function (e) {
  return {t:e};
});
console.log(list);
```